# Is Terracotta used professionally?

Tags: session, session-state, terracotta, stateless, stateful

Today at work I had a discussion with my co-workers and my boss about stateless / stateful beans (we just finished a project using JSF, it was the first time anyone at this company did something JSF related) and my boss said that he doesn't really like Session scoped beans (or even conversation / KeepAlive scoped ones). One of his arguments was that if we have for example 4 Tomcats and there is a request from the user then we aren't really sure that it will be "captured" by the same Tomcat every single time and the problem is that if during the first time a request comes and a session bean is created it's created only on that one Tomcat and the others don't know about it.

One of the solutions he mentioned was a so called "sticky session" which enforces requests from a given user to be handled by the same Tomcat every time. A second solution according to him would be storing all the data in the "view", but that would mean storing the whole state in the POST, somehow I don't really like that idea. Then he mentioned storing the state in the DB and querying it if a request that requires it arrives. I thought that it would be a really huge performance hit, but he said that it really wouldn't be a concern since the DBs should be prepared for such tasks.

The last solution which I'm interested in was the Terracotta Server which, from what he told us, is supposed to store the session bean for all Tomcats (which are synchronized with it and then if a requests comes in they look for session beans inside Terracotta). Seems kinda cool and scalable, but he said that he didn't really see it ever used in large professional systems, is that right? I tried some info on it but failed, is there something wrong with Terracotta that stops people from using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used by professionals, just look a their customers page.

http://www.terracotta.org/company/customers?src=/index.html